# Updates to billing.phtml not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, rwd-theme, billing

Can't seem to figure out how to remove the following fields from the Billing step:

1) Register with us for future convenience 
2) Ship to this address 
3) Ship to different address

[image]

I am trying to change the `billing.phtml` to comment out the fields not needed but having no luck on the front-end. Even after clearing cache, reindex etc... nothing is changed.

So far I have tried to modify the `billing.phtml` files in the following locations:

design/frontend/**rwd**/default/template/*persistent*/checkout/billing.phtml 
design/frontend/**base**/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml 
design/frontend/**base**/default/template/*persistent*/onepage/billing.phtml

Where can I edit the billing page so I can remove unneeded fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one of the extensions I installed was overwriting my billing.phtml file

I was using this extension to skip the first step on the checkout process:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/skip-checkout-step-1.html

I had to edit the billing.phtml file located at
template/skipstep1/billing.phtml

Hope this helps someone.